# How to define properties of a Service Bean from application.yml in Grails 3?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-config

I was able to define properties of a service bean from Config.groovy.

Quoting *Book The Definitive Guide to Grails 2*

> Listing 10-6. Configuring Beans Using Config.groovy

```
beans {
    albumArtService {
        artworkRequestUrl = 'http://itunes...'
    }
}
```

> One advantage of this approach is that thanks to the features offered
>   by Config.groovy, you can easily specify per-environment values rather
>   than hard-coding the value into the AlbumtArtService class. With that
>   Configuration code in place, the hard-coded value may be removed form
>   the AlbumArtService class. The property still needs to be declared as
>   a field in the class but should not be assigned a value. The framework
>   will take care of initialising the property with the value specified
>   in Config.groovy

In Grails 2 I have defined properties of a service bean as described above.

Now in Grails 3 I am trying to define service properties in my application.ml file:

```
environments:
    development:
        beans:
            transactionalMailService:
                mandrillApiKey: XAPIKEYVALUEX
            shareWithShoptimixUseCaseService:
                appStore: https://itunes/myapp
        grails:
            serverURL: http://localhost:8080
        dataSource:
            driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dial

    ....
    ...
    ..
    .
```

Then in my service:

```
class TransactionalMailService {

    def mandrillApiKey

    ....
    ...
    ..
    .
}
```

The property is not being set though. Any idea how to do this in Grails 3?

Answer (score 1):

I have a [solution](http://grails3.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-configure-artefact-beans.html), but to me it's still a work-around.

I like the way controller and service bean properties can be set in Grails 2. But being unable to get it to work the same way in Grails 3, I chose to go with setting the properties in *Bootstrap.groovy*

```
def init = { servletContext ->
        myService.someProperty = 'some value'
...
}
```

I don't consider this *the answer*, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put multiple documents into the same YML file.

```
beans:
   transactionMailService:
      mandrilApiKey: real key
---
spring:
    profiles: development
beans:
      transactionMailService:
        mandrilApiKey: dev key
```

this is (I think) because beans are configured by spring